# Was this review audit valid?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits, triage, spam

So, I just recently failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/21941464) review audit by choosing "Requires Editing". I did this because the question was really long and had a bunch of unnecessary details, and a couple of variable assignments appeared to unneededly be in bold. It looked like it could easily be salvaged by shortening the text at the top and changing the bold to normal code formatting and probably just removing the links altogether.  Now, I can see why this was marked as spam, but it seemed to me like easily salvage spam.

Did I review this correctly, or should I have flagged as spam?

For <10k users, [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T3Tf4.png) is a screenshot of the question.

Comment: I can't see the question since it's been deleted but you shouldn't try to salvage spam posts.

Comment: @BSMP it didn't seem to me like obvious spam. Mostly it was just a variable that shouldn't have been bold or pointed to a spammy link.

Comment: I took a look for the question and see "This question was deleted as spam or offensive" message - sounds like the post is spam-flagged and deleted by Community user.

Comment: [Clearer screenshot for <10k](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QePon.png)

Comment: Makes no sense to me as spam for this isolated case. Only mods can explain.

Comment: FWW it is no longer deleted; it was revived by a moderator just now.

Comment: There is no such thing as salvageable spam. If you can see that it is spam, you should have voted to have it deleted. I would have failed the same review because it looks like a legitimate question to me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks for bringing this to our attention.

Seems like this post was deleted due to reaching the spam flags threshold, and was deleted by Community.

I have disputed the spam flags and edited the question so that it doesn't look spammy due to the unbroken wall of text and link formatting issue as seen in your screenshot.

Comment: How can -2 be a threshold for spam deletion?

Comment: A mod spam flag will cause the threshold to be reached immediately.

Comment: @PetterFriberg just to clarify it had one spam flag. A moderator then saw that and assumed that it was spam, which made them to cast another spam flag, thus making it a score of -2. Once the moderator cast their flag, the post was nuked as spam (moderator spam flags are binding). Given that the question was nuked by a moderator spam flag, it became a candidate for audit. Now Samuel disputed the spam flags, which subsequently undeleted the post, and also cleared the audit. Hope that is clear.

Comment: Thanks for clarification, *"reaching the spam flags threshold, and was deleted by Community"*  is a diplomatic way of saying it but it's better to be clear when one of you mods missclick. We know you have tons of work so no need to be diplomatic.

Comment: In all fairness, if someone posts a question containing a URL to yet another damn betting site, they only have themselves to blame if it gets taken as spam.

Comment: Mods don't have to agree on stuff; it's not good assume it was a misclick.

Comment: _"Just to clarify it had one spam flag. A moderator then saw that and assumed that it was spam, which made them to cast another spam flag"_ If moderators cast spam votes purely on the basis that there are already spam votes, what's the point in waiting for moderators to cast votes? This is identical to just letting one spam flag nuke a post. The moderator should look at the post and judge it independently, before casting their hammer vote, no? Perhaps I'm missing something. But the word "assume" here is rather concerning to me.

Comment: @Lightness, you should have pinged me in the comment, could have responded earlier. For starters, we usually decline loads of spam flags. People flag as spam for strange unknown reasons. We do check the post clearly, and most of us are in fact very strict regarding the spam flag rules. (In this particular case, the moderator told us that they thought it was spam, which is why I used the word assumed)

Comment: @BhargavRao Okay, seems like "assumption" wasn't actually involved, just a mis-use of the term? In which case, that sounds better.